# Passing params from functional component to class component in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have functional component where I am passing params at `onPress`. Below is the code:

**PAGE1**

```
const onPress = (data) => {
    navigation.goBack();
    route.params.onPress(data);
  };
```

I was able to pass this to a functional component, where I was getting the data, and was able to update my state in the functional component. Below is the code snippet from **functional component**:

**PAGE2**

```
function gotoSearch() {
    navigation.navigate('SearchScreen',{
      onPress:(data)=>{
        console.log("Location Selected",data);
        updateStateVar({
          ...stateVar,
          address_line_1: data.address_line1,
          address_line_2: data.address_line2,
          area: data.area,
          city: data.city,
          country: data.country,
          pincode: data.postCode,
          lat:data.lat,
          lng:data.lng,
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I have another component which is a class component, I tried to do the same thing, but is showed me the error. Below is the code snippet from **class component**:

**PAGE3**

```
gotoSearch = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SearchScreen'), {
      onPress: (data) => {
        console.log("Location Selected",data);
      }
    }
```

}

**error**:

```
cannot read property of 'onPress' of undefined

const onPress = (data) => {
    navigation.goBack();
    route.params.onPress(data);
                 ^
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to export onPress function

```
export const onPress = (data) => {
    navigation.goBack();
    route.params.onPress(data);
  };
```

then use it inside your class component

```
gotoSearch = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SearchScreen'), {
      onPress: (data) => {
        console.log("Location Selected",data);
      }
    }
```

if your function exists in a different file and then first import it and then use

```
import {onPress} from './file.js'
```